# cppcheck skips .hpp files

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have a heavily templated project that is using the system of having a `.h` file with the function declarations `#include` a corresponding `.hpp` with the function definitions. However, `cppcheck` doesn't seem to parse the `.hpp` files, and I don't see an option to change the file extensions that it parses. How do people usually handle this?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that one can not change the extension cppcheck is looking for when scanning a directory. There are some other options:

1. Have a text file with a list of all your `*.hpp` files and run cppcheck with the `--file-list=<file>` parameter.
2. Run cppcheck for every `*.hpp` file directly, giving the filename on command line.
3. Create `*.cpp` files that include the include those `*.hpp` files so that cppcheck can find them. Those could be tests for your library.

Comment: I am a Cppcheck developer. I agree with this answer. I recommend option 3.

Comment: @michalsrb For Option 3, do I need to actually build those .cpp files (or "that file" if I can just use one for all of the .hpp references?) with the project (i.e. do they need a main(), etc.)? Or do I just literally have a giant list of `#include "Class1.hpp"` `#include "Class2.hpp"` in a file called something like "HppForCppcheck.cpp" that doesn't actually get referenced by the project anywhere?

Comment: @DanielMarjamäki Any thoughts on my question in the previous comment?